# What does “Queencess” mean?

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between ***queen*** and ***queencess***? Does it have something to do with ***princess***? And more generally what does it mean?

I have heard this phrase several times in my neighborhood.

Comment: Where is your neighbourhood?

Comment: Montreal, Canada

Comment: It sounds like a portmanteau of "queen" and "princess".  Hard to guess the meaning, though, without any context -- possibly a young girl that acts like a queen and expects everyone to do her bidding.

Answer (score 1):

**Queencess** is not a word in the English dictionary. It is blend word formed by combining queen and princess. It is quite a trending hashtag and name though as to why you might have heard it in your neighborhood.